# How can i wraptext to the new row in excelize

Tags: go, excelize

as athor answer on internet

people doing the
`

```
WrapText: true
```

`
to make WrapText in a cell,
but today,I want to WrapText to a new row,
and when i type "/n" in cell ,code will wrapText to a new row.

this is what i expecting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIVdU.png)
can finally becom this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFJQo.png)
and this is my code
`

```
paymentTermStyle, _ := f.NewStyle(`{
        "alignment":{
            "wrap_text":true
        },
        "font": {
            "family": "Times New Roman"
          }
    }`)

    f.SetCellStyle("PI", "A48", "A48", paymentTermStyle)
```

`
thanks for helping

Comment: You can't "wrap text to a new row", that's just now how spreadsheets work. Text wrapping is within a cell. If you want some of the data in the next row, you need to put it in a cell in the next row.

Comment: but i am wonder that ,is there any solution can help me to let the contex which in  one cell ,
finally move to a new row?

Answer (score 0):

add "WrapText:true" in excelize.Style struct like this

```
paymentTermStyle, _ := f.NewStyle(&excelize.Style{
Alignment: &excelize.Alignment{
            Horizontal: "center",
            Vertical:   "center",
            WrapText:   true,
        },
        Font: &excelize.Font{Size: 11, Bold: true},
    })
  f.SetCellStyle("PI", "A48", "A48", paymentTermStyle)
```